# extra material for JavaScript: Understanding the weird parts

Tags: javascript

I am currently taking Tony Alicea's course of JavaScript: Understanding the Weird Parts. The course is a really good one but still I would like to have some more practice. What kind of books,lectures, exercise, websites would you recommend to look through along with that course? Particularly I am interested in solving algorithmic problems in JS.

Answer (score -1):

[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/) is an excellent, readable way to learn code. Also, StackOverflow is a great way to get questions answered, which I see you're already here.